# Почему в файл копируются непечатные символы? Помогите в отладке программы

Tags: c, алгоритм, файлы, отладка

Я пытаюсь реализовать алгоритм [lzw](https://habr.com/ru/post/132683/)

Прошу помочь в отладке программы. Суть проблемы такая:

Есть текстовый файл со строкой

```
 abacabadabacabae
```

Сжать его у меня (вроде как) получилось. Я получил файл с бинарным кодом сжатой строки. Вот его содержимое:

```
6100 0000 6200 0000 6100 0000 6300 0000
6162 0000 0101 0000 6100 0000 6400 0000
0401 0000 0501 0000 0201 0000 0301 0000
0801 0000 0901 0000 6100 0000
```

По моему там не хватает кода последней буквы `e`, но это не суть. Теперь из этого файла с бинарным кодом мне нужно получить исходную строку (или пока строку без `e`). Но в результате работы функции я получаю текст с большим количеством непечатных символов

```
abacabaadabac<0x01>aabac<0x01>adabacabac<0x01>abac<0x01>ad<0x04><0x05><0x02>abac<0x01>ad<0x04><0x05><0x02><0x03>aa
```

Уже смотрел ASCII таблицу. Это символы:

```
 0x01 — START OF HEADING (Начало С-строки?)
 0x02 — START OF TEXT (Начало текста в С-строке?)
 0x03 — END OF TEXT (Конец С-строки?)
 0x04 — END OF TRANSMISSION (Конец передачи данных (был достигнут конец входного файла?))
 0x05 — Enquiry (Вообще не могу предположить, что он означает в моем случае)
```

Хотя непечатных символов ни в промежуточном файле, ни в итоговом, быть в файле вообще не должно! (Я прописал для этого условие в обоих функциях) Помогите разобраться, в чем причина такого поведения программы! Заранее всем огромное спасибо. Вот весь код Снабдил комментариями насколько мог.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "lzwlib.h"
// слова будем хранить в структуре

typedef struct Word {
    unsigned int code;
    char* value;
} Word;

void* checkNull(void* ptr) {
    if (ptr == 0) {
        printf("%s", "out of memory");
        exit(37);
    }
    return ptr;
}

// функция сжатия принимает на вход путь к файлу, который надо сжать

FILE* compress(const char* inputFileName) {
    // Далее идет код, в котором формирую имя файла с расширением .lzw, наш выходной поток
    //...

    char* outputFileName = checkNull(malloc(strlen(inputFileName) + 5));

    strcpy(outputFileName, inputFileName);

    char* ex = strchr(outputFileName, '.');

    if (ex) strcpy(ex, ".lzw");

    else strcat(outputFileName, ".lzw");
    // Теперь открываем наши файлы
    
    FILE* outFile;
    outFile = fopen(outputFileName, "wb");

    FILE* inFile;
    inFile = fopen(inputFileName, "r");

    free(outputFileName);

    // свободный код

    unsigned int freeCode = 256;
    // Переменная, где будем хранить текущий код символа из входного файла
    int currentCharCode;
    
    // Словарь состоит из 4096 слов

    Word* dictionary[4096];
    // Префикс и суффикс текущего слова
    Word prefix;
    Word sufix;

    // очистка словаря от мусора
    for (int i = 0; i < 4096; i++) {

        sufix.value = checkNull(malloc(2 * sizeof(char)));
        sufix.value[0] = 0;
        sufix.value[1] = '\0';
        dictionary[i] = checkNull(malloc(sizeof(Word)));
        dictionary[i]->value = checkNull(malloc(2 * sizeof(char)));
        strcpy(dictionary[0]->value, sufix.value);
        dictionary[i]->code = 0;
    }

    // Начальная инициализация словаря
    // Значения Суффикса и префикса будем хранить в виде С-строк, чтобы иметь возможность использовать функции strcat() strcpy()
    // значению суффикса выделяем 2 байта

    sufix.value = checkNull(malloc(2 * sizeof(char)));
    sufix.value[0] = 0;
    sufix.value[1] = '\0';
    dictionary[0] = checkNull(malloc(sizeof(Word)));
    dictionary[0]->value = checkNull(malloc(2 * sizeof(char)));
    strcpy(dictionary[0]->value, sufix.value);
    dictionary[0]->code = 0;

    sufix.value = checkNull(malloc(2 * sizeof(char)));
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        // Переводим ASCII В C-строку, записываем ее в словарь
        sufix.value[0] = i;
        sufix.value[1] = '\0';
        dictionary[i] = checkNull(malloc(sizeof(Word)));
        dictionary[i]->value = checkNull(malloc(2 * sizeof(char)));
        strcpy(dictionary[i]->value, sufix.value);
        dictionary[i]->code = i;

    }

    // После инициализации в словаре хранятся строки "[ASCII-код]\0"

    free(sufix.value);

    // Записываем в префикс с-строку [ASCII-код]\0 первого символа из входного потока

    currentCharCode = fgetc(inFile);

    prefix.value = checkNull(malloc(2 * sizeof(char)));
    prefix.value[0] = currentCharCode;
    prefix.value[1] = '\0';
    prefix.code = currentCharCode;
    // будем использовать переменную для проверки есть ли слово в словаре
    int inDictionary = 1;

    // пока не конец файла Переприсваиваем currenCharCode код нового символа

    while ((currentCharCode = fgetc(inFile)) != EOF) {
        // формируем суффикс
        if (currentCharCode > 31) {
            sufix.value = checkNull(malloc(2 * sizeof(char)));
            sufix.value[0] = currentCharCode;
            sufix.value[1] = '\0';
            sufix.code = currentCharCode;
        }
        if (strlen(prefix.value) <= strlen(dictionary[freeCode - 1]->value) && inDictionary == 1) realloc(prefix.value,
                                                                                                          strlen(prefix.value) +
                                                                                                          2);
        if (prefix.value == NULL) prefix.value = strcpy(prefix.value, sufix.value);
            // К нашему текущему префиксу добавляем суффикс Теперь слово у нас расширилось на один символ
        else prefix.value = strcat(prefix.value, sufix.value);

        // Проверяем словарь
        for (int i = 0; i < freeCode; i++) {
            // если мы найдем в словаре наш префикс, то коду префикса назначаем соответствующий код из словаря
            if (strcmp(prefix.value, dictionary[i]->value) == 0) {
                prefix.code = dictionary[i]->code;
                inDictionary = 1;
            } else {
                inDictionary = 0;
            }
            if (inDictionary == 0 && i == freeCode - 1 && strlen(prefix.value + 1) != 0) {
                //Если выполнилось условие проверки, то это значит, что расширенного слова нет в нашем словаре, значит
                // Выводим в выходной поток код слова, которое есть в словаре
                fwrite(&prefix.code, sizeof(int), 1, outFile);

                // выделяем память под слово с первым свободным кодом
                dictionary[freeCode] = checkNull(malloc(sizeof(Word)));
                // выделяем память под значение нового слова в словаре
                dictionary[freeCode]->value = checkNull(malloc(strlen(prefix.value) + 1));
                // копируем новое слово в словарь
                dictionary[freeCode]->value = strcpy(dictionary[freeCode]->value, prefix.value);

                // Назначаем ему код
                prefix.code = freeCode;
                dictionary[freeCode]->code = prefix.code;
                // Мы записали расширенное в словарь

                // Теперь текущим словом должен стать суффикс расширенного слова

                strcpy(prefix.value, sufix.value);
                prefix.code = sufix.code;

                free(sufix.value);

                // и увеличиваю код свободного слова
                ++freeCode;
                inDictionary = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(inFile);
    fclose(outFile);
}

FILE* decompress(const char* inputFileName) {
    const char* ex2 = ".lzw";
    if (strstr(inputFileName, ex2) == 0 || strchr(inputFileName, '.') == 0) {
        printf("%s", "incorrect file");
        exit(38);
    }

    char* outputFileName = checkNull(malloc(strlen(inputFileName) + 1));
    strcpy(outputFileName, inputFileName);
    char* ex = strchr(outputFileName, '.');
    if (ex) strcpy(ex, "2.txt");

    else strcat(outputFileName, "2.txt");
    // Теперь открываем наши файлы

    FILE* outFile;
    outFile = fopen(outputFileName, "w");

    FILE* inFile;
    inFile = fopen(inputFileName, "r");

    free(outputFileName);

    unsigned int freeCode = 256;

    int currentCharCode;

    Word* dictionary[4096];

    Word prefix;
    Word sufix;
    
    // Начальная инициализация словаря
    // Значения Суффикса и префикса будем хранить в виде С-строк, чтобы иметь возможность использовать функции strcat() strcpy()
    // значению суффикса выделяем 2 байта

    sufix.value = checkNull(malloc(2 * sizeof(char)));
    sufix.value[0] = 0;
    sufix.value[1] = '\0';
    dictionary[0] = checkNull(malloc(sizeof(Word)));
    dictionary[0]->value = checkNull(malloc(2 * sizeof(char)));
    strcpy(dictionary[0]->value, sufix.value);
    dictionary[0]->code = 0;

    sufix.value = checkNull(malloc(2 * sizeof(char)));
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        // Переводим ASCII В C-строку, записываем ее в словарь
        sufix.value[0] = i;
        sufix.value[1] = '\0';
        dictionary[i] = checkNull(malloc(sizeof(Word)));
        dictionary[i]->value = checkNull(malloc(2 * sizeof(char)));
        strcpy(dictionary[i]->value, sufix.value);
        dictionary[i]->code = i;
    }

    // После инициализации в словаре хранятся строки "[ASCII-код]\0"

    free(sufix.value);

    sufix.value = checkNull(malloc(2 * sizeof(char)));
    prefix.value = checkNull(malloc(2 * sizeof(char)));
    int codeInFile = 0;
    
    while (!feof(inFile)) {
        fread(&codeInFile, sizeof(int), 1, inFile);

        if (codeInFile < freeCode && codeInFile > 31) {

            sufix.value[0] = codeInFile;
            sufix.value[1] = '\0';

            if (prefix.value == NULL) {
                strcpy(prefix.value, sufix.value);
            } else {
                strcat(prefix.value, sufix.value);
                // Проверяем есть ли в словаре получившаяся строка
                for (int i = 0; i < freeCode; i++) {
                    // Если нет —  добавляем ее в словарь, увеличиваем freeCode и обнуляем, выходим из цикла проверки
                    if (i == (freeCode - 1) && strcmp(dictionary[i]->value, prefix.value) != 0) {
                        dictionary[freeCode] = checkNull(malloc(sizeof(Word)));
                        dictionary[freeCode]->value = checkNull(malloc(strlen(prefix.value) + 1));
                        strcpy(dictionary[freeCode]->value, prefix.value);
                        dictionary[freeCode]->code = freeCode;

                        ++freeCode;

                        free(prefix.value);
                        prefix.value = checkNull(malloc(sizeof(char) * 2));
                        break;
                    } else if (strcmp(dictionary[i]->value, prefix.value) == 0) break;
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < freeCode; i++) {
                if (codeInFile == dictionary[i]->code) {
                    fprintf(outFile, "%s", dictionary[i]->value);
                    printf("%s", dictionary[i]->value);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(inFile);
    fclose(outFile);
}
// тестирую сжатие
int main() {
    char* s = "toCompress.txt";
    char* s2 = "toCompress.lzw";
    FILE* compressed = compress(s);
    FILE* decompressed = decompress(s2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Отформатируйте код нормально

Comment: @dIm0n вроде бы выровнял, извиняюсь

Comment: `else strcat (outputFileName, "2.txt");` — с этой строчки не выровнено. Поставьте 3 кавычки + ctrl+v из вашей IDE + три кавычки (такие ```)

Comment: @dIm0n не помогло...

Comment: 1) вы использовали не те кавычки, которые я указал 2) оберните в эти кавычки весь ваш код (уже отформатированный в IDE), а не только кусок. В редакторе есть справка справа вверху

Comment: @dIm0n Обернул в блок вроде

Comment: Теперь 4 пробела перед кодом везде :)

Comment: @dIm0n Вроде все))

Comment: Чтобы быть в чём-то уверенным, проводятся тесты. Запустите работающий компрессор, и посмотрите реальный вывод. У меня большое подозрение, что бинарный поток неверный.